# How to configure Spring Boot to execute a SQL query once with JdbcTemplate?

Tags: java, sql, datasource, spring-boot, jdbctemplate

I use Spring Boot and JdbcTemplate with Maven. I would like to execute a single SQL query in the database at start.

Here is a example of the application.yml file :

```
spring
    datasource
      driverClassName: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
      url: jdbc:oracle://localhost/test
      username: dbuser
      password: dbpass
      initialize: true
```

I found on the web that it can be done by creating a data.sql file in the root of the classpath (/resources directory by example) (Visit http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html for initialization a database using Spring JDBC). So I just create a data.sql file in the /resources directory, near the application.yml file, with content :

```
alter session set nls_numeric_characters='.,';
```

But, the data.sql file is not executed when starting the application. The implementation seems easy yet. Did I forget any parameterizations or dependencies ?

I would be pleased to have some help. Thanks.

Comment: How do you know it is not executed? Your SQL only changes 'nls_numeric_characters' for the current session, and not all the sessions. To be sure place a breakpoint in this file: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceInitializer.java and see what exactly happens.

Comment: I know it is not executed because I have inserted an UPDATE query in the data.sql file and the table is not updated.

Comment: Have you tried to debug the class I have linked to you? Usually it is the fastest way to get your answer + you will learn something new about Spring :)